# How do I make my action supported in UK English

Tags: action, actions-on-google, google-home

I have couple of actions live on Google Home but they are only available in US English. I am in UK so I need to support UK English or keep my Google home ever locked to US English.

I was thinking languageCode parameter in JSON will accept a list or multiple such parameters but documentation suggests it only allows en-US

Comment: This post may be relevant https://plus.google.com/+WaynePiekarski/posts/3Dozat8LjHh

Comment: Got this back from Google support which kind of tells the same story: We appreciate your interest in developing Actions on Google.

Actions on Google platform is currently only available for English (United States), and this is configured with the settings in your Google Home app. We are working on making Actions on Google available in other languages and regions, but we do not have a formal release date at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Actions were not supported in UK English until today: https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/actions-for-british-english.html

Your actions should now work.

Comment: Yup thanks. Got an email that Google going to port all en-US actions to en-UK so hopefully we don't have to do anything and it will all be automatically available to our users

Answer (score 0):

Now UK English is available in actions on Google console. You can go to your application's settings and can change your application's language. 
Here is the link - https://console.actions.google.com